# Custom FrameLayout that adds items to sub FrameLayout?

Tags: android

I am trying to make some kind of button that can have content added to it like it is done to a FrameLayout. For example:

```
<ch.pboos.android.ui.ContentButton ...>
  <LinearLayout ...>
    <TextView .../>
    <TextView .../>
  </LinearLayout>
</ch.pboos.android.ui.ContentButton>
```

So far I made a view that xml file that would represent how i want the button to look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/white_button_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/white_button_margin">
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:padding="@dimen/white_button_padding"
      android:background="@drawable/channel_bg">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/content" ...>
      <!-- content -->
    </FrameLayout>
    <ImageView ... android:src="@drawable/right_triangle" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I would like to make a custom FrameLayout (ch.pboos.android.ui.ContentButton) that will add that view and allow me to add views into the content area of that xml above.

Any suggestions on how to get this working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Dispatch all touch events occurring on ContentButton to custom button via overriding dispatchTouchEvent. And add on click listener to this button (this helps you to recognize and handle only clicks, not e.g. moves)

2) override addView this way:

```
addView(...) {
   if(inflatingInProgress) {
      super.addView(view);         
   }
   else {
      // add view to @+id/content
   }
}
// where flag inflatingInProgress initially = true and is set to false after 
// finishing inflating the layout for ContentButton
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.